# Unable to encrypt file using bouncycastle lib

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, gnupg

Hi I am trying to encrypt a text file using bouncycastle lib but getting this error java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes

THis is the code

```
public class RSAEncryptFile {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String publicKeyFilename = "/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/pubkey";
        String inputFilename = "/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/test";
        String encryptedFilename = "/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/javaprogram";

        RSAEncryptFile rsaEncryptFile = new RSAEncryptFile();
        publicKeyFilename = "/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/pubkey";;
        inputFilename = "/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/tesco.txt";
        encryptedFilename = "/Users/Rajesh/Desktop/javaprogram";
        rsaEncryptFile.encrypt(publicKeyFilename, inputFilename, encryptedFilename);

    }

    private void encrypt (String publicKeyFilename, String inputFilename, String encryptedFilename){

        try {

            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

            String value = "";
            String key = readFileAsString(publicKeyFilename);
            BASE64Decoder b64 = new BASE64Decoder();
            AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey =
                    (AsymmetricKeyParameter) PublicKeyFactory.createKey(b64.decodeBuffer(key));
            AsymmetricBlockCipher e = new RSAEngine();
            e = new org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding(e);
            e.init(true, publicKey);

            String inputdata = readFileAsString(inputFilename);
            byte[] messageBytes = inputdata.getBytes();
            int i = 0;
            int len = e.getInputBlockSize();
            while (i < messageBytes.length)
            {
                if (i + len > messageBytes.length)
                    len = messageBytes.length - i;

                byte[] hexEncodedCipher = e.processBlock(messageBytes, i, len);
                value = value + getHexString(hexEncodedCipher);
                i += e.getInputBlockSize();
            }

            System.out.println(value);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(encryptedFilename));
            out.write(value);
            out.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static String getHexString(byte[] b) throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
            result +=
                    Integer.toString( ( b[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String readFileAsString(String filePath)
            throws java.io.IOException{
        StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(filePath));
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int numRead=0;
        while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
            String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
            fileData.append(readData);
            buf = new char[1024];
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(fileData.toString());
        return fileData.toString();
    }

}
```

The content of the input public key file  /Users/Rajesh/Desktop/pubkey

```
pub dsa1024 2019-07-29 [SC]
4EB9C4A3CEF9CCA26C1446G7H1D511656GH98D9E
uid [ultimate] TEST <TEST@test.com>
sub elg4096 2019-07-29 [E]
```

Can someone please help me. My use case is , I want to encrypt file using this public key.

Comment: Your 'pubkey' file contains _metadata_ for a key _cluster_ displayed by PGP, not an actual key, and certainly not an actual key in SubjectPublicKeyInfo format -- see https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.8on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PublicKeyFactory.html -- because PGP does not use that format. If you had an actual PGP key block, you could read the key and use it to PGP-encrypt data -- which is hybrid in this case ElGamal (not RSA) plus symmetric Xecrets describes -- using instead the classes in bcpg-*.jar .

Answer (score -1):

Without actually writing the whole code, you should know that asymmetric ciphers such as RSA are essentially never used to encrypt data, such as a file. It is typically used to encrypt a fixed size symmetric key, which then is used in an appropriate mode of operation with a symmetric cipher to encrypt the data.

There are so many caveats with encrypting actual data directly with RSA, don't go there.

When encrypting the data, you'll also need to store some meta data, typically at the absolute minimum an initialization vector, IV, so you will need to define a "file format", which describes how the file is structured with it's meta data and the cipher data.

If it's educational assignment, go back and explain it's a not an appropriate assignment. A more appropriate similar assignment would be to encrypt a symmetric key of fixed size, that will always be encryptable within a single 'block' of RSA encryption.

If you're actually planning to use it in the real world, use a ready-made library or utility for the purpose. Don't roll your own. There are many to chose from, I have written one using BouncyCastle, even if it's in C# it's very similar to Java you could look there https://github.com/xecrets/xecrets-file-cli to get an idea. Or just use it as a ready made utility for the purpose!